# Question on Self Adjoint operators

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, problem-solving, adjoint-operators

We consider the operator $L=-i\frac{d}{dx}$ with $x \in (a,b)$. Check whether L is a self-adjoint operator for
$\mathcal{D}(L)=\{u \in C[a,b]:u(a)=u(b)\}$

My thought is the following

To check whether $L$ is self-adjoint on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)={u \in C[a,b]:u(a)=u(b)}$, we need to verify whether it satisfies the following property:
$$\langle Lu,v \rangle=\langle u,Lv \rangle$$

Let $u,v \in \mathcal{D}(L)$. Then, we have:

\begin{align*}
\langle Lu, v \rangle &= \int_a^b (-i\frac{d}{dx}u(x))\overline{v(x)} dx \newline
&= -i[u(x)\overline{v(x)}]_a^b + i\int_a^b u(x)\frac{d}{dx}\overline{v(x)} dx \newline
&= i\int_a^b u(x)\frac{d}{dx}\overline{v(x)} dx \hspace{15mm} \text{(since $u(a)=u(b)$)}\newline
&= i[u(x)\overline{v(x)}]_a^b - i\int_a^b \frac{d}{dx}u(x)\overline{v(x)} dx \newline
&= i[u(x)\overline{v(x)}]_a^b + \langle u, -i\frac{d}{dx}v \rangle \newline
&= \langle u, Lv \rangle \hspace{16mm} \text{(since $v(a)=v(b)$)}
\end{align*}

Therefore, we have shown that $L$ is self-adjoint on the domain $\mathcal{D}(L)=\{u \in C[a,b]:u(a)=u(b)\}$

Is this way of thinking correct?

Comment: That shows it's symmteric - which is not enough for self-adjointness because $L$ is an unbounded operator.  The answer is that it's not self-adjoint on the domain given - but its closure is self-adjoint.  The domain of $\overline{L}$ is the subspace of functions $f\in L^2[a,b]$ such that $f$ has a derivative in the weak sense and its derivative $f'$ is also in $L^2[a,b]$.

Comment: @JohnDoe thank you very much. That was really helpful